isMutable always returning False
async def get_metadata(self, address):
    metadata_account_info = await self.get_pda(address)

    if metadata_account_info.value:

        self.metadata_layout = CStruct(
            "updateAuthority" / Bytes(32),
            "mint" / Bytes(32),
            "data" / CStruct(
                "name" / Bytes(32),
                "symbol" / Bytes(10),
                "uri" / Bytes(200),
                
            ),
            "isMutable" / Bool
            
        )

Anyone knows what's wrong with this script why the value of isMutable is always returning False? I also tried using Struct from construct instead of borsh construct to struct the bytes but the result is still the same.

You'll need to preface the name / symbol / uri with 4 bytes for the length. Try this:
        self.metadata_layout = CStruct(
            "updateAuthority" / Bytes(32),
            "mint" / Bytes(32),
            "data" / CStruct(
                "name_length" / Bytes(4),
                "name" / Bytes(32),
                "symbol_length" / Bytes(4),
                "symbol" / Bytes(10),
                "uri_length" / Bytes(4),
                "uri" / Bytes(200),
            ),
            "isMutable" / Bool
            
        )


I tried that format and still does not work but thanks, I encountered new issues
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/16691/needing-aprropriate-bytes-input-to-return-true-value-of-ismutable

isMutable defines whether you can update the metadata account of an SPL token.
Read more https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update
You're probably reading from tokens that cannot have their metadata updated.

The function is designed to retrieve the metadata of a token address, I have already retrieved the data that I need, like name, symbol, uri, but the isMutable part is always returning False even if the token is Mutable when I checked it on telegram bot scanners or rugcheck.xyz.

Have you cross-checked with other APIs?

I already verified a specific  token address that returned False but on Solscan, Helius, Rugcheck and telegram scanners, they returned True, but at this moment, I am currently using rugcheck api just to fetch the appropriate value for isMutable and sometimes it is having an issue because it has limit so I want to retrieve it without the use of third party API.
