Needing aprropriate Bytes input to return true value of isMutable
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from borsh_construct import CStruct, String, U8, Bool
from construct import Bytes

client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")

def get_metadata(address: str):

    try:
        metadata_account_info = get_pda(address)

        if metadata_account_info.value:
            metadata_layout = CStruct(
                "update_authority" / Bytes(32),
                "mint" / Bytes(32),
                "name" / String,
                "symbol" / String,
                "uri" / String,
            )

            isMutable_layout = CStruct(
                "updateAuthority" / Bytes(32),
                "mint" / Bytes(32),   
                "data" / CStruct(
                    "name_length" / Bytes(4),
                    "name" / Bytes(32),
                    "symbol_length" / Bytes(4),
                    "symbol"/ Bytes(32),
                    "uri_length" / Bytes(10),
                    "uri" / Bytes(200),
                ),   
                "isMutable" / Bool
            )
                        

            metadata_data = metadata_layout.parse(metadata_account_info.value.data)
            isMutable_data = isMutable_layout.parse(metadata_account_info.value.data)
            isMutable = isMutable_data.isMutable
            name = metadata_data.name
            symbol = metadata_data.symbol


            print(f"{name}\n{symbol}\n{isMutable}\n{"-" * 30}")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error getting metadata: ", e)


def get_pda(token_address: str):
    new_token = Pubkey.from_string(token_address)
    token_metadata_program = Pubkey.from_string("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s")

    metadata_pda = Pubkey.find_program_address([b"metadata", bytes(token_metadata_program), bytes(new_token)], token_metadata_program)[0]
    metadata_account_info = client.get_account_info(metadata_pda)
    

    if metadata_account_info.value:
        return metadata_account_info
    else:
        print("Metadata account not found.")
        return None

def main():
    mint1 = "DezXAZ8z7PnrnRJjz3wXBoRgixCa6xjnB7YaB1pPB263"
    mint2 = "3T9mBXQzfAn8Rf1LKDutvGMTd1EruJbFh3cM7MSMq3Py"
    mint3 = "Ap5zQ4V62riDNnYN9ihFyNM8brdiYenkvMpHeF3Epump"
    mint4 = "8HYCrj9AFaWXtwMbYdZBsGC27fNctKDriNDJP72gBubE"
    
    get_metadata(mint1)
    get_metadata(mint2)
    get_metadata(mint3)
    get_metadata(mint4)

main()

On isMutable_layout, whenever I change the symbol bytes to 32, the mint3 and mint4 show the true value of isMutable which is True and mint1 and mint2 become false, but when I change the value of bytes to 10, the mint1 and mint2 will show the True value which is True.
All of them are mutable tokens, you can verify it on different scanners. Mint1 and Mint2 is an old tokens, "Bonk" and "Chippy" which I think affects the structuring of the layout.
I already tried to set the symbol length to bytes(4) and uri_length to bytes(4) but all of them returned False. I tried to monitor the newly listed or created tokens and compare the value of isMutable to different scanners like Rugcheck and Helius at the same time, and the bytes(32) of the symbol matches them.
But still, the example mint addresses are all mutable tokens and I don't want to retrieve an inappropriate value in the future scanning by just relying on making the symbol bytes to 32.

You might be looking in the wrong place for the mutable flag. All of the layouts and sizes are defined at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/d580a0b144aeac7972b73490cde55b4877351b63/programs/token-metadata/program/src/state/metadata.rs#L22, so you can count up from the start all the way up to the mutable byte at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata/blob/d580a0b144aeac7972b73490cde55b4877351b63/programs/token-metadata/program/src/state/metadata.rs#L27
Counting up, it looks like you want byte at index 497:
1 + 32 + 32 + 4 + 32 + 4 + 10 + 4 + 200 + 2 + 1 + 4 + 5 * 34 + 1

